NDSolve can't find Neumann Value on domain
Trying to solve for the temperature around an axisymmetric thin disk. Edges of the domain are DirichletConditions which work fine, but the solver can't find the NeumannValues along the top and bottom of the disk. Can't tell what I'm doing wrong....
{rchamb = 0.15, hchamb = 0.2, rdisk = 0.01, hdisk = 0.001, DTop = 0, 
  DBot = 200};
domain = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, -hchamb/2}, {rchamb, hchamb/2}], 
   Rectangle[{0, -hdisk/2}, {rdisk, hdisk/2}]];
BCs = {DirichletCondition[T[r, z] == 293, 
    r == rchamb || z == hchamb/2 || z == -hchamb/2]};
Soln = NDSolve[{D[T[r, z], {r, 2}] + (1/r) D[T[r, z], r] + 
      D[T[r, z], {z, 2}] == 
     NeumannValue[DTop, r < rdisk && z == hdisk/2] + 
      NeumannValue[DBot, r < rdisk && z == -hdisk/2] + 
      NeumannValue[DBot - DTop*((z + hdisk/2)/hdisk), 
       r == rdisk && z <= hdisk/2 && z >= -hdisk/2], BCs}, 
   T, {r, z} \[Element] domain];
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[T[r, z] /. Soln], {r, 0, rchamb}, {z, -hchamb/2, hchamb/2}, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Axisymmetric Solution to Laplace's Equation"]



This is a typical mesh issue. Since the cut in the area is very small, it is necessary to create a very thin mesh around this area using MeshRefinementFunction as follows
<< NDSolve`FEM`

{rchamb = 0.15, hchamb = 0.2, rdisk = 0.01, hdisk = 0.001, DTop = 0, 
  DBot = 200};
domain = 
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, -hchamb/2}, {rchamb, hchamb/2}], 
  Rectangle[{0, -hdisk/2}, {rdisk, hdisk/2}]]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[domain, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    Block[{r, z}, {r, z} = Mean[vertices]; 
     If[r <= 2  rdisk && z^2 <= rdisk^2, area > 0.0000001, 
      area > 0.01]]]]

mesh["Wireframe"]


Now we can successfully solve the problem as
BCs = {DirichletCondition[T[r, z] == 293, 
    r == rchamb || (z == hchamb/2 || z == -hchamb/2)]};
Soln = NDSolve[{D[T[r, z], {r, 2}] + (1/r)  D[T[r, z], r] + 
      D[T[r, z], {z, 2}] == 
     NeumannValue[DTop, r < rdisk && z == hdisk/2] + 
      NeumannValue[DBot, r < rdisk && z == -hdisk/2] + 
      NeumannValue[DBot - DTop*((z + hdisk/2)/hdisk), 
       r == rdisk && z^2 <= hdisk^2/4], BCs}, 
   T, {r, z} \[Element] mesh];

Visualization around cut, and in the chamber,
{ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[T[r, z] /. Soln], {r, 0, 2  rdisk}, {z, -2 hdisk, 
   2  hdisk}, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Axisymmetric Solution to Laplace's Equation"], 
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[T[r, z] /. Soln], {r, 0, rchamb}, {z, -hchamb/2, hchamb/2},
   Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Axisymmetric Solution to Laplace's Equation"]}
  



Nice answer! I tried to check NeumannValue at r==rdisk using Plot[Derivative[1, 0][    Function[{r, z}, Evaluate[(T[r, z] /. Soln[[1]]) ]]][rdisk,    z], {z, -hdisk/2, hdisk/2}, GridLines -> {None, {DTop, DBot}}] but result seems to be incorrect. Any idea?

@UlrichNeumann Try to use divergent form of equation :)

Thanks, but I don't understand. Aren't Derivative[1,0][T][r,z],Derivative[0,1][T][r,z] the correct  flux conditions at boundary r=const,z=const?

@UlrichNeumann Let try Derivative[1, 0][T][rdisk, 0] /. Soln[[1]], and Derivative[0, 1][T][rdisk/2, hdisk/2] /. Soln[[1]], and -Derivative[0, 1][T][rdisk/2, -hdisk/2] /. Soln[[1]]

to long for a comment
I tried to verfify the NeumannValue's from Alex Trounev's nice solution.
solT = NDSolveValue[{D[T[r, z], {r, 2}] + (1/r) D[T[r, z], r] + 
      D[T[r, z], {z, 2}] == 
     NeumannValue[DTop, r <= rdisk && z == hdisk/2] + 
      NeumannValue[-DBot, r <= rdisk && z == -hdisk/2] + 
      NeumannValue[DBot - DTop*((z + hdisk/2)/hdisk), 
       r == rdisk && z^2 <= hdisk^2/4], BCs}, 
   T, {r, z} \[Element] mesh];

NeumannValue's (Specified flux(NDSolveValue) plotted in Dashed,Red)
Plot[Derivative[0, 1][solT][r , hdisk/2], {r, 0, rdisk}, 
 GridLines -> {{0, 
    rdisk}, { {DTop, {Dashed, Thickness[Large], Red}}}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "NeumannValue z== hdisk/2 && 0<r<rdisk"]


    Plot[Derivative[0, 1][sol][r , -hdisk/2], {r, 0, rdisk}, 
 GridLines -> {{0, 
    rdisk}, { {DBot, {Dashed, Thickness[Large], Red}}}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "NeumannValue z==-hdisk/2 && 0<r<rdisk"]


Plot[{Derivative[1, 0][sol][rdisk, z], 
  DBot - DTop*((z + hdisk/2)/hdisk)}, {z, -hdisk/2, hdisk/2}, 
 GridLines -> {{-hdisk/2, hdisk/2}, {DTop, DBot}}, 
 PlotRange -> {DTop, DBot}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Dashed, , Thickness[Large], Red}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "NeumannValue -hdisk/2<z<hdisk/2 &&  r==rdisk"]


The first two Neumann-conditions aren't as expected as r->rdisk.
The last Neumann-condition deviates strongly from the specification given in `NDSolve/NeumannValue.
What could be the reason for these unexpected results?
